# How to update properties of objects in an array with calculated dynamically value

Tags: javascript, function

I have an array of objects (examples simplified here):

```
array1 = [
  {name: "alfa", par1: 1, value: null},
  {name: "beta", par1: 2, value: null},
  {name: "gamma",par1: 3, value: null},
]
```

An object with some parameters:

```
parameters = {par2: 1, par3: 9}
```

And function calculating value using some properties of objects from array1 and some parameters from parameters object (par1 is from the array object itself and par2,par3 are stored in another object - common for all array1) :

```
func = (par1, par2, par3) => {
  return par1 + par2 + par3
}
```

What is the simplest way to update "value" property in objects in array1 with result of function func?
This is expected result:

```
result = [
  {name: "alfa", par1: 1, value: 11},
  {name: "beta", par1: 2, value: 12},
  {name: "gamma",par1: 3, value: 13},
]
```

There must be an elegant way to achieve this...
Thanks for all help :)

**EDIT:**

Sorry for not clarifying it enough...
The key of the problem is using the **func** function. The example above is very simplified, in fact the function has complicated formula (using *reduce* for **parameters** object is not possible) and using over 20 parameters.
It needs to use all parameters at the same time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `func`

```js
let array1 = [
  {name: "alfa", par1: 1, value: null},
  {name: "beta", par1: 2, value: null},
  {name: "gamma",par1: 3, value: null},
]

let func = (par1, par2, par3) => par1 + par2 + par3

let parameters = {par2: 1, par3: 9}

array1.forEach(e => e.value = func(e.par1, ...Object.values(parameters)))

console.log(array1)
```

One alternative usuing `forEach`, `Object.values`  and `reduce`

Scroll through all the objects in the array arra1 `{name: '...', p1: ..., values: null}'` and use `reduce` to sum all the values ​​of the `parameter` object, then just add the result with the value of the `p1` object of `arra1`

```js
let array1 = [
  {name: "alfa", par1: 1, value: null},
  {name: "beta", par1: 2, value: null},
  {name: "gamma",par1: 3, value: null},
]

let parameters = {par2: 1, par3: 9}


array1.forEach(e => e.value = Object.values(parameters).reduce((ac, curr) => ac + curr, e.par1))
  
  
console.log(array1)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is the simplest solution for me :) Still don't understand why I cannot just use "...parameters" instead of "...Object.values(parameters)"?

Comment: When you use '... ob', it is as if you unstructured that object to obtain `key: value`, and in the case of a function parameter it would not make sense to have: `func (1, par2: 1, par3: 9) `.

Comment: Something similar to the result you asked, would be if you changed the function `func`, for example: `func = (par1, {par2, par3}) = par1 + par2 + par3`. In this situation, the parameter `{par2, par3}` expects to receive an object and unstructures it to get the values ​​of the keys of the same name

Comment: In the above case you would use: `func(2, parameters)` without using '...'

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `func` to be a curried function. This way you can first pass `parameters` to it and extract the `par2` and `par3` properties/values from it using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). This function will return a new function (add) which accepts another object with a `par1` property and closes over the `par2` and `par3` values. You can then use `.map()` on your `array1` to return a new array with each object containing a `value` property. The value of the `value` key will be the result of passing `o` into the function returned by `func` - which will add par1, par2 and par3 together.

See example below:

```js
const array1 = [
  {name: "alfa", par1: 1, value: null},
  {name: "beta", par1: 2, value: null},
  {name: "gamma",par1: 3, value: null},
];

const parameters = {par2: 1, par3: 9}
const func = ({par2, par3}) => ({par1}) => {
  return par1 + par2 + par3;
};

const add = func(parameters);
const res = array1.map(o => ({...o, value: add(o)}));
console.log(res);
```

A scalable version of the object can be achieved by grabbing the values of the `parameters` object and summing them using `.reduce()`:

```js
const array1 = [
  {name: "alfa", par1: 1, value: null},
  {name: "beta", par1: 2, value: null},
  {name: "gamma",par1: 3, value: null},
];

const parameters = {par2: 1, par3: 9}
const func = params => {
  const sum = Object.values(params).reduce((t, n) => t+n, 0);
  return ({par1}) => par1 + sum;
};

const add = func(parameters);
const res = array1.map(o => ({...o, value: add(o)}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be a nice solution but I would rather not modifying the func function. The curried function is new and strange concept for me... What is the difference when function takes all arguments together vs one by one, if there are no operations performed in between? What is practical application for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's one or two argument is enough for you function to return the new value for the value property.

You can even get rid of the base param and just have it inside the function.

```js
const array1 = [{
    name: "alfa",
    par1: 1,
    value: null
  },
  {
    name: "beta",
    par1: 2,
    value: null
  },
  {
    name: "gamma",
    par1: 3,
    value: null
  },
]

const func = (base, par1) => {
  return base + par1;
}

const result = array1.map(x => ({
  ...x,
  value: func('1', x.par1)
}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
array1 = [
  {name: "alfa", par1: 1, value: null},
  {name: "beta", par1: 2, value: null},
  {name: "gamma",par1: 3, value: null},
];
parameters = {par2: 1, par3: 9};

array1.forEach(item=>item.value=item.par1+parameters.par2+parameters.par3);

console.log(array1);
```

And for unknown number of parameters (disregarding their names):

```js
array1 = [
  {name: "alfa", par1: 1, value: null},
  {name: "beta", par1: 2, value: null},
  {name: "gamma",par1: 3, value: null},
];
parameters = {par2: 1, par3: 9, x: 3, y:7};

array1.forEach(item=>
  item.value=item.par1+
  Object.values(parameters).reduce((acc,cv)=>acc+cv,0)
)

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Using "func" is essential for me. And it is not just adding (see question EDIT), Thanks anyway